# CSharpCodeProvider does not see the Stack<T> class under System.Collections.Generic

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, pseudocode, csharpcodeprovider

I'm building a pseudocode translator and compiler.
It translates the pseudocode to code by performing several string operations, then it uses the [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class to compile it, and finally it tries to run it.

After a few tests, in the case that the translated/output code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TranslatedProgram
{
    public static void ReadLine(ref int destiny)
    {
        destiny = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public static void InsertInStack(ref Stack<int> originalStack, int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inserting the value " + value + " to the stack.");
        originalStack.Push(value);
        foreach (int current in originalStack)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("|" + current);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("_______");
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int value = new int();
        Stack<int> data = new Stack<int>();
        ReadLine(ref value);
        InsertInStack(ref data, value);
    }
}
```

When the application sends this code to the CSharpCodeProvider, it doesn't compile. In the compilerResults, I get the following error: "The type or namespace name 'Stack' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" [(CS0246)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

BUT when I put this code, exactly as it is, inside a new project from the VS IDE, it works perfectly.

Any guess?

Thanks.

Edit:

I'm calling the CSharpCodeProvider compiler from VB by doing the following:

```vb
Private Sub CompileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CompileButton.Click
        If ApplicationSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Compiler As New Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
            Dim Results As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults
            Results = Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(New CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters With {.GenerateExecutable = True, .OutputAssembly = ApplicationSaveFileDialog.FileName}, CodeTextBox.Text)
            If Results.Errors.Count = 0 Then
                Shell(ApplicationSaveFileDialog.FileName)
            Else
                For Each Exception As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError In Results.Errors
                    ExceptionsTextBox.AppendText(Exception.ErrorText)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

How could I include a reference to System.dll?

Comment: When you compile with CSharpCodeProvider, did you include the `System.dll` as an assembly reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that, when you compile, you have a reference to the dll that holds `Stack<>`, which is `System.dll`.

You can add a reference by using property `ReferencedAssemblies` of the `CompilerParameters` class:

```
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, "MyFile.cs");
```

Comment: Which property can I use to give the compiler that information? It's my first time working with this class, I can't find any property or parameter to do that

Comment: I added some more info to the answer.